# Is it possible to execute a SQLPLUS script using ODP.NET (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess)?

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlplus, odp.net

I've got a console app that connects to a database (using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`) and then tries to execute a bunch of `SQL*PLUS` scripts located on my local hard drive.

Unfortunately although my app works for simple SQL Statements (`SELECTS`) it doesn't appear to work for `SQL*PLUS`.

The Code:

```
    var script = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Automation\\script.sql");

    using (var objConn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
        objCmd.Connection = objConn;
        objCmd.CommandText = script;
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        try
        {
            objConn.Open();
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Script.sql**  - executes without error in SQL Developer

```
    DEFINE CODE_PATH = C:\Automation
    @"&&CODE_PATH\Test.sql"
```

**Test.sql**  - executes without error in SQL Developer\my app without `SQL*PLUS`

```
    SELECT ID FROM data.SOME_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM < 100
```

**Error:**

```
    ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Comment: you may need reference some other library of the client. have a look at [sqlserver way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449646/how-can-i-execute-a-sql-from-c)

Comment: It should work, I tried the code it is working. Try the same sql statement inside your code instead of using "script" file, if it is working it should work with that "script" file too.

Comment: @imsome1 that's encouraging that it works for you. So if I remove the script element and pass a string instead: "DEFINE CODE_PATH = C:\\Automation\r\n@\"&&CODE_PATH\\TEST.sql\"" I still get the error

Comment: Ok, print the "script" value using Console.WriteLine(script); and check the output

Comment: Looks okay printed to the Console. Even if I pass: "@C:\\Automation\\test.sql" I still get the error

Comment: it should be  @"C:\Automation\test.sql" not   "@C:\\Automation\\test.sql", @ sign before the path

Comment: But then its not a SQL PLUS command. I understand where you're coming from escaping the \, but that's not what I'm trying to do here. [Link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php)

Comment: Try `objCmd.CommandText = "BEGIN " + script + "; END;";` However, depending on statements inside your script.sql it may fail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @WernfriedDomscheit but that didn't help. If I wrap a begin end around my SQLPLUS script I get an ORA-06550, which is the same error I'd get if I wrapped a begin end around SQLPLUS in SQL Developer. I just don't think that's something you'd want to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

ODP.NET and other Oracle programming interfaces (OCI, OCCI, JDBC etc) are designed to execute SQL, PL/SQL and calls to stored procedures and functions. They are not designed to process SQL*Plus syntax (which BTW contains lots of other non-SQL, non-PL/SQL commands aside from just the "@" symbol - for example "show errors").

SQL * Plus scripts were designed to be executed by SQL*Plus alone, but in recent years SQL Developer, Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, and some other Oracle tools have added parsers for it. These parsers are not exposed via a public API however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if it's possible to execute slqplus through ODP.NET, I suspect it's not.

So as a workaround, I'm going to call the sqlplus.exe directly.

Code:

```
    static void execString(string userName, string password, string scriptFileName, string dataSource)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
        processInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0}/{1}@{2} @{3}", userName, password, dataSource, scriptFileName);

        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    }
```

Thanks to [Rich's post from 8 years ago for the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657623/is-there-a-net-interface-to-oracle-sqlplus?answertab=active#tab-top)