# Visual Studio 2017 Connection with Oracle SQLPLUS

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio, sqlplus

I have to create an application which will invoke Oracle SqlPlus commands. The requirements for this application are:

1. When the application is executed it should ask for a user name and password to connect to the Oracle database.
2. Once connected successfully the application has to run some sql statements to fetch data from the database.
3. Once the data is fetched it should be exported to a .htm file in a
   path provided by the user.

This is the same as spooling from SqlPlus, but from a .NET application.

Is there any method to achieve the same result, like calling SqlPlus commands from a .NET application?

I googled a lot but could not find any appropriate solution. Hopefully I'll get a proper answer here.

Comment: why would you need sqlplus? If you can connect to the database, you can connect to the database as sysdba and execute most database administration commands over the database connection, using either ODP or ODBC. You probably can't mount or open the database (although I haven't tried that to verify), but as long as the database is open you should not need sqlplus.

Comment: Since you already have the SqlPlus commands, would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657793/937093) work for you? Basically wrapping the execution of SqlPlus in a .NET application.